# Flex-grow takes up its own margin as well when scrolling is needed

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container, in my case the body and html tags are the containers. And then I have 3 divs in them and I want the last one to fill the remaining vertical space available while still having a margin.

The third div is generated dynamically so I can't predict what height it's gonna need. The problem is, if it grows too much and a scrollbar is required, the bottom-margin it used to have goes away too. If a scrollbar is NOT required and doesn't appear, the margin is still there and everything looks like I want it to.

[image]

I tried to draw what I meant as best as I could in the above image. The 1st case is what I want to happen all the time, regardless of whether there's a scrollbar or not. The 2nd picture is what actually happens, the blue div loses its bottom margin, despite having it set.

Here's my CSS for the html and body tags (they contain the 3 divs, including the blue one):

```
html,
body
{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items: center;
    background: #494d5f ;
}
```

and here's my code for the 3rd div, the blue one:

```
.bottomDiv
{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   background: #a0d2eb ;
   
   align-items: center;
   width: 97%;
   margin-bottom:1.5%;
   flex: 1 1 auto;
   
   padding-top:1%;
   padding-bottom:1%;
     
}
```

Maybe I didn't clarify well enough but the 3rd div in my case, the blue one grows just like it should, fully obeying its margins UNTIL a scrollbar appears and is needed. No matter the amount of growth it has to do, it does it perfectly while respecting its margin. But if it has to grow "out of bounds" of the page so to say, as in, a scrollbar is needed to display all the webpage then its margin is simply gone. **IF there is NO scrollbar, everything looks perfect.**

Comment: please add a minimal reproduciable code snippet (**Ctrl + M**) containing all necessary code to reproduce the issue. This also includes HTML as CSS without corresponding HTMl structure is useless in most of the cases. Not that creating a minimal reproduciable code snippet (with a focus on minimal) is also the first step in debugging for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this line: `body { height: 100%; }` to: `body { min-height: 100vh; }`.

With that line the body will have a height of at least the screen height (100vh) but allows i proper overflow as it is allowed to eb alrger then the screen. As such the margins wont get removed.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #494d5f;
}

.topDiv,
.midDiv {
  width: 97%;
  height: 50px;
}
 
.topDiv {
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  background-color: red;
}


.midDiv {
  background-color: blue;
}


.bottomDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #a0d2eb;
  align-items: center;
  width: 97%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
}

#height:checked + label::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 150vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="topDiv"></div>
<div class="midDiv"></div>
<div class="bottomDiv">
  <input type="checkbox" id="height" name="height">
  <label for="height">checkmark me to extend box height</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! A very important note to whoever stumbles upon this :it HAS to be 100vh, 100% won't work. I've seen your post before you edited it and I think it had % instead of vh in it, switched it up to vh and it worked.

Comment: glad this works for you. No my edit just added the checkbox to increase the 3rd div's height for demonstration.

Answer (score -1):

I've put an example, so you may try this approach:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  outline: 1px solid purple;
}

#header {
  height: 30px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

#middle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* height: 100vh; */
  /* flex-direction: column; */
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

#footer {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">...</div>
  <div id="middle">...</div>
  <div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

Try to remove `#footer` and see that #middle fills the entire screen till the end.
In addition if you need any margins so you have to modify the container like this: `#page { ..., margin: 10px; height: calc(100vh - 20px); }`

Comment: try to remove #footer and see that #middle fills the entire screen till the end

Comment: in addition if you need any margins so you have to modify the container like this:       #page { ..., margin: 10px;  height: calc(100vh - 20px); }

Comment: @tacoshy sure, you can do that for me ?

Comment: just did, that, please delete your comments then - as a side note, `<style>` belongs in the `<head>` section not in the bottom of the `<body> section´.

Comment: because the content is the same as in the snippet. there i no use to the sandbox. If the link changes or the content it would become useless. Sandboxes may be used if they add extra data that could be cruicial but would be long to contain in a snippet. none of that applies to your sandbox.

Comment: @tacoshy oh really ?

Comment: @tacoshy so you are just like destroying working approaches, right?

Comment: I did not destroy workign approaches. Your sandbox had no content that is not shown in the snippet. As such your sandbox holds no extra value to be used.

Comment: Maybe I didn't clarify well enough but the 3rd div in my case, the blue one grows just like it should, fully obeying its margins UNTIL a scrollbar appears and is needed. No matter the amount of growth it has to do, it does it perfectly while respecting its margin. But if it has to grow "out of bounds" of the page so to say, as in, a scrollbar is needed to display all the webpage then its margin is simply gone.

Comment: @JeromeDurham if the blue div is more than reaming height of the screen then you will have vertical scrollbar

Comment: @tacoshy the sandbox snipped has working solution, FYI

Comment: re-read again: the sandbox has no content that the snippet has not. As such the sandbox is unecessary. its just a copy of the code snipept in your anwser. A sandbox may be used to offer more code then the code snippet itself. However as it is a 1:1 copy it remains unecessary.

Comment: I'm completely fine with the scrollbar appearing, it MUST appear in order for the page to work properly if the blue div is too "tall"(height-wise) . However the scrollbar appearing makes the margin of the blue div completely vanish. IF the scrollbar is not needed and does not appear, all's fine.   So to reiterate: EVERYTHING works perfectly as long as a scrollbar is not needed. When it appears (it appears because it is needed) the blue/3rd div loses its bottom margin which it should have at all times

Comment: @JeromeDurham just remove height: 100% from "html, body"

Comment: @Andy removing height:100%; from html,body makes flex-grow not work anymore. Like yes, when a scrollbar is needed, the 3rd div  has the bottom margin like it should, but otherwise, it doesn't grow when it should(when there's a lot of empty space in the html,body tags) .

Comment: @JeromeDurham you don't have flex on body either; the better way is to have a flex wrapper for your div elements;

Comment: @JeromeDurham this version has the third div that exceeds page height with bottom margin: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-benz-1rxnc?file=/index.html

Comment: @Andy my html,body are flex-boxes, I've written the css for them in my post. I can't get flex-grow to work without having 100% height as a parameter for the html,body tags. If I put height:100% on the 3rd div too it still doesn't work but it breaks everything instead. If I put 100% height ONLY on the 3rd div, it works, but the flex growth is completely gone, so it keeps the margin, but the huge empty space is not filled anymore .   My HTML is like this : html, body tags and inside them the 3 divs, one after another. I can't figure out for the life of me. Everything is a flex box

Comment: @JeromeDurham tried `min-height: 100vh;` istead of `height: 100%;` already?